# DataMapper: can't list object instances and DateTime not instantiable?

Tags: ruby, datetime, datamapper

First things first: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and DataMapper 1.2.0.

I created the following seemingly simple model:

```
class User
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,           Serial
    property :username,     String
    property :password,     BCryptHash
    property :name,         String
    property :email,        String
    property :created_at,   DateTime
end
```

I can fire this up in an irb shell, it creates a database, and everybody's happy. But then I try:

```
tim = User.new(:username => "tim", :password => "password", :name => "Tim", :email => "my@email.com", :created_at => Time.now)
```

I receive back a User instance, printable to the console and with all its attributes intact. I can run `tim.save!` and see success. However, if I try to list users at this point, I run up against an error:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.all
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=> 
irb(main):002:0> User.first
NoMethodError: undefined method `new!' for DateTime:Class
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:153:in `next!'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:153:in `block in read'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:276:in `with_connection'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-do-adapter-1.2.0/lib/dm-do-adapter/adapter.rb:141:in `read'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/repository.rb:162:in `read'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/model.rb:377:in `first'
    from (irb):5
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>''
```

Any clues? Nothing else is really turning up on SO or Google for not supporting `#inspect`, and the Ruby stdlib docs distinctly lack a `new!` method for DateTime.

Comment: I note that you've specified that column type as `DateTime`, yet you're creating yourself using `Time.now` instead of `DateTime.now`; if you change that, does it help?

Comment: Good catch, but I tried both (after reading somewhere in the DM docs that they're interchangeable on creation). Same result.

Comment: OK; sorry I can't help more, I use [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org), not DM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out - it had to do with the version of the `do_sqlite3` gem I was using not having been reinstalled since I switched to Ruby 1.9.3. As mentioned in [this bug](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/issues/144), I needed to reinstall all my `do_*` gems to relink against 1.9.3 before it worked.